# php parse css class string

Tags: php, regex, class, inline-styles

I need to get css class name, attributes and values in order to apply inline css style to a div.
Currently, I can retrive css class name information from a string like this :

```
$class = ".custom_class {
    margin-top: 0px !important;
    border-top-width: 0px !important;
    border-right-width: 0px !important;
    border-left-width: 0px !important;
    padding-top: 250px !important;
    padding-bottom: 250px !important;
    background-image: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/old-car.jpg?id=3663) !important;
    border-left-color: #dd3333 !important;
    border-right-color: #dd3333 !important;
    border-top-color: #dd3333 !important;
}";
```

How can I get or regex all css attributes and values in order to include them in a div like this:

```
<div class="custom_class" style="margin-top: 0px !important;border-top-width: 0px !important;border-right-width: 0px !important;border-left-width: 0px !important;padding-top: 250px !important;padding-bottom: 250px !important;background-image: url(http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/old-car.jpg?id=3663) !important;border-left-color: #dd3333 !important;border-right-color: #dd3333 !important;border-top-color: #dd3333 !important;"></div>
```

I tried with this: `preg_match("/{(.*?)}/", $class, $match);`
But it outputs with brackets. And for the class name I don't know how to do that.

Comment: The important question here is WHY?

Comment: In the first sentence of my question. How can I retrieve string in the bracket and outside the bracket of the $class var.

Comment: Yes, but WHY? It's totally backwards to convert CSS stylesheet into inline styles, inline styles are good for debugging and setting with javascript, but should be avoided!

Comment: It's not the question that. I need to do that because of some ajax method that I use. My question is just how can I regex this expression.

Comment: I'm just saying that you most likely have some alternative and better way to do what you want. See http://xyproblem.info/

Comment: please don't be harsh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ou're near with your regex `preg_match("/{(.*?)}/", $class, $match);`, just escape the curly brackets and retrive the data in `$match[1]`:

```
preg_match("/^([\w.]+)\s*\{(.*?)\}/s", $class, $match);
$classname = $match[1];
$style = $match[2];
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. How can I get the class name outside the bracket?